# Scraping reviews from product page using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, product, review

'''I'm writing this code but it is only giving me top 4 reviews. I want all the review's of a product from product page.
Please help me out with my code..'''

```
url = 'https://mamaearth.in/product/glow-serum-foundation-almond-glow'
r = requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
pro = html.fromstring(r.content)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
button2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@style="color: rgb(0, 174, 239); cursor: `pointer;"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button2)
review = pro.xpath('//div[@class="ReviewItem_content"]/text()')
reviewer_details = pro.xpath('//span[@class="ReviewItem_header_name"]/text()')
```

Comment: The reason you only receive 4 results is because only 4 are initially loaded. The others are only shown when you click "view all reviews". The data is stored in JSON which you can access for the results.

Comment: hey!! thanks for replying, but I'm hitting that 'view all reviews' button with my code then why it is not giving me all the reviews??

Comment: And also i don't know how to extract reviews from json.

Comment: Where are you intiating driver? it looks like you're trying to use selenium functions without setting up a driver but using requests instead. As for extracting reviews from json, you would have to find the html selector, read that as json (using the json library) and target the data from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data in the json and return a list of dictionaries, each containing the review information:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://mamaearth.in/product/glow-serum-foundation-almond-glow'
r = requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
reviews = data['review']
```

An example of the output:

```
{'@type': 'Review', 'datePublished': '2022-06-21 11:31:40', 'reviewBody': 'Great product', 'author': {'@type': 'Person', 'name': 'Tahamira khatun'}}
{'@type': 'Review', 'datePublished': '2022-06-17 14:18:01', 'reviewBody': 'Very nice for products.... I like ', 'author': {'@type': 'Person', 'name': 'Uma'}}
{'@type': 'Review', 'datePublished': '2022-06-08 17:16:03', 'reviewBody': "It's super awesome gives instant glow ✨️ ", 'author': {'@type': 'Person', 'name': 'Swati '}}
{'@type': 'Review', 'datePublished': '2022-06-06 15:59:25', 'reviewBody': 'Really great product ♥️', 'author': {'@type': 'Person', 'name': 'Bincy'}}
{'@type': 'Review', 'datePublished': '2022-06-04 09:06:03', 'reviewBody': 'Awesome', 'author': {'@type': 'Person', 'name': 'Kareema'}}
{'@type': 'Review', 'datePublished': '2022-06-01 06:12:54', 'reviewBody': 'Nice  product ', 'author': {'@type': 'Person', 'name': 'Tiki mishra '}}
{'@type': 'Review', 'datePublished': '2022-05-31 19:14:13', 'reviewBody': 'I m happy Than you', 'author': {'@type': 'Person', 'name': 'Naziya'}}
{'@type': 'Review', 'datePublished': '2022-05-21 18:10:39', 'reviewBody': 'Ubtan face wash ', 'author': {'@type': 'Person', 'name': 'Love you mama earth ❤️'}}
```